# UPDATE my table using one query

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
Table1
------------
-id:int (Key)
-chapter:int
-page:int
-words:int   
-chars:int

Table2
------------
-id:int (Key)
-chapter:int
-page:int
-value:int
```

Table1 contains number of words for all pages and table2 contains some of pages (not all of them!)

*How can I update table2 and fill "value" by corresponding field ("words") in table1?(Where table1.chapter=table2.chapter AND table1.page=table2.page)*

Is it possible to update all table using one query? Thank you.

Comment: You've gotten your query almost written already in your question description.  You just need to change it to SQL. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.value = (SELECT table1.words
                    FROM table1
                    Where table1.chapter = table2.chapter
                    AND table1.page = table2.page);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    Table2
SET
    Table2.value = Table1.words,
FROM
    Table2
INNER JOIN
    Table1
ON
    Table1.page = Table2.page AND
    Table1.chapter = Table2.chapter
```

Yes you can do that, the above example should work, or at least give you an idea on how to do it